# How to compare json int to Android versionCode of separate app

Tags: java, android, json

I am attempting to add a function to that will check a json file on my server for the versionCode of an app outside of my own and if the versionCode in json on the server is > the one of the outside app, then do an update action. However, I am experiencing issues getting the versionCode of the outside app. The versionCode always returns 0 instead of the actually version of the outside app. Why doesn't it return the proper version? Here is my code:

This is supposed to fetch the versionCode of the app package specified by the json string:

```
    public static int getinstVersionCode(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        try {
            return mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(Constants.PACKAGE_NAME, 0).versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This activity part holds the json package name value:

```
static final String APK_VERSION_CODE = "versionCode";
static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "package";
```

This is the json code on the server:

```
{
"versionCode":1,
"package":"com.example.app",
}
```

And the method to compare them:

```
            int apkCode = obj.getInt(Constants.APK_VERSION_CODE);

        int versionCode = AppUtils.getinstVersionCode(mContext);
        if (apkCode > versionCode) {
        do update action...
         }
```

Comment: The question is...? What's going wrong? Any stacktrace?

Comment: are you looking for force update ?

Comment: @Blady214 the issue is that the versionCode that should be returned from the outside app is returning 0 instead of the actual versionCode

Comment: @AbuQauod Yes, I am trying to update apps outside of my own

Comment: is `apps outside of my own ` means not your own app?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to give my app the ability to check and update other apps that are not mine. @ישואוהבאותך